# How do I force double-quotes when dumping YAML?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a small script to automate some things in YAML files.

I read the original YAML file and convert it into a hash and then [dump](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.6/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html#method-c-dump) it to the file after modifying it:

```
File.open(output_file, "w") do |out|
  YAML.dump(modified_hash, out)
end
```

That works fine, but it removes double-quotes around the string if they aren't needed. That's valid YAML, but it doesn't look very nice.

I could add a space at the end of every string to force single-quotes, but I'm not too happy with that. Is there any way of forcing double-quotes around strings?

Comment: Optional quotes is like, one of the three big differences of YAML to JSON. The third is an attractive nuisance and you probably don't use it. Perhaps you could just JSON?

Comment: no, unfortunately I am forced to use YAML.
I would also be fine with an external tool that adds the quotes automatically

Comment: JSON is a YAML subset (fully for YAML 1.2, practically-fully for earlier versions).

Comment: You probably need to use a Psych custom emitter. Also see Psych::Nodes::Scalar and Psych::Handler#scalar.

Comment: currently I have the idea to add some weird symbols that are unlikely to be used (like "☙") to every value and later walk through the dumped file and replace those symbols with empty string.

That would be a weird method but it will probably work to add quotes around the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, it's weird, but it works.

To force **single quotes**, I went through the hash and appended `"foobar "` (note the space) to every value. After using `YAML.dump`, I opened the file again and replaced `"foobar "` with empty string.

To force **double quotes**, I found that appending `"foo \nbar"` does the job. Again, I then open the file and replace `"foo \\nbar"` with empty string. Weird, but works.

Note that you probably want to chose something less likely used than foobar.

Answer (score 4):

This works pretty well. I got it from [here](https://github.com/ruby/psych/issues/322#issuecomment-328408276)

```
require 'psych'

ast = Psych.parse_stream DATA.read

# First pass, quote everything
ast.grep(Psych::Nodes::Scalar).each do |node|
  node.plain  = false
  node.quoted = true
  node.style  = Psych::Nodes::Scalar::DOUBLE_QUOTED
end

# Second pass, unquote keys
ast.grep(Psych::Nodes::Mapping).each do |node|
  node.children.each_slice(2) do |k, _|
    k.plain  = true
    k.quoted = false
    k.style  = Psych::Nodes::Scalar::ANY
  end
end

puts ast.yaml
```

Comment: For anyone else who needs to pass options to `ast.yaml`, like the line width, pass them as the second argument: `ast.yaml(nil, {line_width: -1})` (see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/psych/rdoc/Psych/Nodes/Node.html#method-i-to_yaml)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Ruby version of @jomo's answer, for anyone's future reference:

```
def ensure_quotes(h)
  h.each do |k, v|
    if v.is_a?(Hash)
      ensure_quotes(v)
      next
    end
    h[k] = v + "__ensure_quotes__\n "
  end
end

def dump_yaml_with_double_quotes(yaml_file)
  yaml = YAML.load_file(yaml_file)
  File.open(yaml_file, 'w') do |f|
    YAML.dump(ensure_quotes(yaml), f, line_width: -1)
  end
  `sed -i '' "s/__ensure_quotes__[\\]n //g" #{yaml_file}`
end
```

It loads the YAML from a file, recursively appends the magic quoting string to all the values in a YAML object, then dumps that YAML to the same file, and then uses `sed` to remove occurrences of the magic string from the output file.