# Force quotes in yaml

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, yaml

I have a ruby hash that is something like this:

```
myhash = { title: 'http://google.com'}
```

I'm trying to add this to a yaml file like this:

```
params['myhash'] = myhash
File.open('config.yaml', 'w') do |k|
  k.write params.to_yaml
end
```

The problem is that YAML is removing the  quotes  around the links even though they are needed (they contain ':').

According to several questions on Stackoverflow, YAML should only remove the quotes when they are not needed.

I found a [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316333/how-do-i-force-double-quotes-when-dumping-yaml), but it's really ugly and I prefer not to use it if there was another solution.

I suppose that yaml should be including the quotes in this case. Is there any reason why it's not doing this?

Note: the links are dynamically created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes aren't necessary for your example string.  From [the specs](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2791260):

> Normally, YAML insists the “:” mapping value indicator be separated from the value by white space. A benefit of this restriction is that the “:” character can be used inside plain scalars, as long as it is not followed by white space.

For example:

```
h = { value1: 'quotes: needed', value2: 'quotes:not needed' }
puts h.to_yaml
```

Results in:

```
---
:value1: 'quotes: needed'
:value2: quotes:not needed
```

Answer (score 1):

After couple hours i found it's easier in python.

usage: `python quotes.py *.yml`

- This script use literal format if string has '\n'.
- Use ruamel to replace yaml lib, yaml lib seems not handle some UTF-8 entry

  ```
  from ruamel import yaml
  import io
  import sys


  class quote_or_literal(unicode):
      pass


  def str_presenter(dumper, data):
      if data.count("\n"):  # check for multiline string
          return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='|')
      else:
          return dumper.represent_scalar('tag:yaml.org,2002:str', data, style='"')


  yaml.add_representer(quote_or_literal, str_presenter)


  def quote_dict(d):
      new = {}
      for k, v in d.items():
          if isinstance(v, dict):
              v = quote_dict(v)
          else:
              v = quote_or_literal(v)
          new[k] = v
      return new


  def ensure_quotes(path):
      with io.open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as stream:
          a = yaml.load(stream, Loader=yaml.Loader)
          a = quote_dict(a)

      with io.open(path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as stream:
          yaml.dump(a, stream, allow_unicode=True,
                    width=1000, explicit_start=True)


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      for path in sys.argv[1:]:
          ensure_quotes(path)
  ```